# Reshaping data.frame from wide format to long format [other examples haven't helped]

Tags: r

I have some trouble to convert my data.frame from a wide table to a long table. At the moment it looks like this:

[image: Data Frame]

I've looked at commands such as [melt] and [reshape] but having trouble to convert the table.
I need it to like like this

```
Monat   Value
2008-01  849
2008-02  771
2008-03  822
.
.
2015-12  719
```

[image: Data frame should be presented like this]

I have tried the following code but its not working:

```
reshape(SuicideTable, direction = "long", varying = list(names(SuicideTable)[13:9]), v.names = "Value", 
        idvar = c("Monat"), timevar = "Value1", times = 2008:2015)
```

Comment: `library(data.table);metl(SuicideTable,1)`

Comment: You might get better responses if you follow [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/11258495) for R, especially if your dataset is defined in a variable.  Otherwise, you're asking others to take the time to create & populate the dataset themselves in order to present a runnable solution.

Comment: To address your specific question, try [`tidyr::gather()`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/).  You'll need to concatenate year & month after that.

Comment: This is a duplicate question, reference: [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `gather` and `unite` for this:

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)

  # example data
  mat <- (matrix(rnorm(12*8, mean = 800, sd = 200), nrow = 12))
  df <- data.frame(months = month.abb, mat)
  colnames(df)[-1] <- 2008:2015

  #    months     2008      2009      2010     2011     2012      2013  ...    
  # 1     Jan 578.1627 1005.3642  622.2480 738.3829 448.1257 1112.2660  
  # 2     Feb 950.1085  857.4998  866.0585 629.5612 848.3288  714.2643  
  # 3     Mar 650.0593  852.8997  797.3760 719.5924 696.3195  793.7964  
  # ...

  df %>% gather(year, Value, - months) %>% 
       unite(Month, year, months, sep = "-")

 #       Month     Value
 # 1  2008-Jan  578.1627
 # 2  2008-Feb  950.1085
 # 3  2008-Mar  650.0593
 # 4  2008-Apr  590.9742
 # 5  2008-May  671.8589
 # 6  2008-Jun  829.1035
 # 7  2008-Jul  755.9633
 # 8  2008-Aug  824.7879
 # ...
```

If you want the months to be represented as numbers and you know that your data set is of the same order as in your picture, you could `mutate` that variable to be represented as number from 1:12

```
   library(stringr)

   df %>% mutate(months = str_pad(1:12, 2,pad = "0")) %>%
          gather(year, Value, - months) %>% 
          unite(Month, year, months, sep = "-")

   #      Month     Value
   # 1  2008-01  578.1627
   # 2  2008-02  950.1085
   # 3  2008-03  650.0593
   # 4  2008-04  590.9742
   # 5  2008-05  671.8589
   # 6  2008-06  829.1035
   # ...
```